# JSON value search

Tags: json

I'm getting below JSON result from a PHP page using ajax request. I tried a lot to get the desired result. I have done below approach but still unable to get as expected.

```
{
    "search": {
        "entry": [
            {
                "attribute": [
                    {
                        "name": "title",
                        "value": [
                            "Mr."
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "mail",
                        "value": [
                            "kiran@gmail.com",
                            "Kiran@yahoo.com",
                            "kiran@hotmail.com"
                        ]
                    }

                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I have tried the following search to get the value using [Defiant.js](http://www.defiantjs.com/#xpath_evaluator)

```
success: function (data) {
var xx=JSON.stringify(data);
//                    var got = $.each(data.search.entry[0].attribute, function (i, v) {
//                        return v;
//                 
//                    });
           alert(xx);
     var z=JSON.search( xx, '//*[name="title"]/value[1]' );
                  alert(z);
                },
```

How would I can get results like `title='Mr'` or `mail='kiran@gmail.com'`.

Answer (score 0):

Why you need regex solution if your json has proper structure. I have seen your code and json and it seems that you need first index value for *title* and *mail*. see following function which can search both *title* and *mail*.

```
var arrt = ' {"search": {"entry": [    {"attribute": [    {"name": "title","value": [    "Mr."]    },    {"name": "mail","value": [    "kiran@gmail.com",    "Kiran@yahoo.com",    "kiran@hotmail.com"]    }]    }]    }}';

    SearchMyWordTT(arrt,"title"); 
    //SearchMyWordTT(arrt,"mail"); 

    function SearchMyWordTT(arr,index){

        arr = JSON.parse(arr);

        for(var i=0;i< arr["search"]["entry"][0]['attribute'].length;i++){          
            if(typeof (arr["search"]["entry"][0]['attribute'][i]['name']) !="undefined" && arr["search"]["entry"][0]['attribute'][i]['name'] == index)
                retIn = arr["search"]["entry"][0]['attribute'][i]['value'][0];
        }

        return retIn;
    }
```

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355102/a-user-massively-tries-to-add-irrelevant-tags-which-i-can-see-while-reviewing-s?cb=1